# APIPIE custom missing parameter message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, documentation

I have used the following apipie code for an action but instead of the missing message I am getting standard "Missing Parameter ip_address"

```
  api :POST, '/addresses.json', "Create a new address for user. Access Token Required"
  error :code => 401, :desc => "Unauthorized"
  error :code => 422, :desc => "Invalid params"
  param :address, Hash, :desc => "Address info", :required => true do
    param :ip_address, String, :desc => "IP address", :required => true, :missing_message => lambda { I18n.t("ip_address.required") }
    param :address_line, String, :desc => "Address Line", :required => true, :missing_message => "Address Line cant be Empty"
    param :city, String, :desc => "City", :required => true
    param :pincode, String, :desc => "pincode"
  end
```

This is the rescue code.

```
  rescue_from Apipie::ParamError do |e|
    puts e
    render json: e.message, status: 422
  end
```

This is what I am getting "Missing parameter ip_address". I have passed the address hash but its missing ip_address

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we had to use the master for apipie instead of 0.3.5.

gem 'apipie-rails', :github => 'apipie/apipie-rails', :branch => 'master'